# Having trouble bug fixing a file encryption cipher (Double Vigenere) - Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, vigenere

Having trouble ironing out bugs with this piece of code, and I've looked at it too much to spot anything at this point.

Basically, the program gets a text file from the user, and will encrypt the text within it.

The way the cipher works is by taking the value of a letter (e.g. a=1 z=26) and shifting that value by the value of a letter in a keyword entered by the user. E.G. word = apple keyword= hello a(1)+h(8)=9(i) for encryption, and the reverse for decryption. This happens with two keywords and then the text is output to a different file.

## Task 3

## Encoding a File

```
def menu():
    choice="y"  
    while choice=="y":
        print("---------------------------")
        print("File Encryption Program")
        print("---------------------------")
        inputfile=input("Enter your input file:\n")
        outputfile=input("enter your output file:\n")
        keyword=input("Enter your first keyword:\n")
        keyword1=input("Enter your second keyword:\n")
        mode=input("Do you wish to encrypt? (E) or decrypt? (D):\n")

        if mode.lower()=="e":
                encrypt=True
                break
        elif mode.lower()=="d":
                encrypt=False
                break
        else:
            print("Invalid mode: ", mode, "exiting program.")
            return
menu()



def textcharacter(encrypt=True):
        pool=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
        letter=""
        letterkeyword=""

        try:
                letterindex=pool.index(letter)
        except:


                return letter

        keywordindex=pool.index(letterkeyword)
        shift=keywordindex+1

        if encrypt==True:
            cipheredindex=(letterindex + shift)%len(pool)

        else:

            cipheredindex=(letterindex - shift)%len(pool)
        offsetindex=pool[cipheredindex]
        return offsetindex
textcharacter()


def textstring():
        encrypt=True
        string=""
        keyword=""
        stringlength=len(string)
        keywordstring=""
        keywordlength=len(keyword)
        for i in range(stringlength):
                keywordstring+=keyword[i%keywordlength]
        new_string=""
        for i in range(stringlength):
                letter=string[i]
                letterkeyword=keywordstring[i]
                new_string=+textcharacter(letter, letterkeyword, encrypt)
        return new_string
textstring()


from re import match


def dualstring():
    encrypt=True
    string=""
    keyword1=""
    keyword=""
    codedstring=textstring()
    dualstring=textstring()
    return dualstring
dualstring()

def readfile():
    try:
            with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
                read_string = f.read()
    except:
            print("Read error")
            raise
    return read_string
readfile()

def writefile():
    try:
            with open(outputfile, 'w') as f:
                    f.write(string)
    except:
            print("Error writing file")
            raise
    return
writefile()

from re import match

def dualfile(inputfile, outputfile, keyword, keyword1, encrypt=True):
    if match('^[a-z]+$',keyword) is None:
            print("Erroneous entry: use lower case letters please.",keyword)
            return
    if match('^[a-z]+$', keyword1) is None:
            print("Erroneous entry: use lower case letters please.",keyword1)
            return
    inputstring=readfile(inputfile)
    print("Input message:\n",inputstring)
    lowercaseinputstring=inputstring.lower()
    outputstring=dualstring(lowercaseinputstring, keyword, keyword1, encrypt)
    print("Output message:\n",outputstring)
    writefile(outputstring,outputfile)
    return
dualfile()
```

Comment: So, what is the expected output and the actual output?

Comment: Also, why is the code example invoking the functions right after defining them? Please improve the formatting.

Comment: I had a problem with the program not actually executing anything other than the base menu if each definition wasn't executed, and it ended up just going in circles around the menu system without actually accomplishing anything. I found more errors without this than I did with it.

Comment: @LauroMoura. Because otherwise the definitions might get stale.

Comment: I'd start by refactoring this. IMHO, this may be written in Python, but is far from any common Python idiom. You may start by using proper (and consistent) arguments to functions instead of mixing global variables and normal arguments. Also, instead of "leaking" the execution and using this def/immediate call trick, try to structure like a classic imperative program, defining the functions and afterwards calling them.

Comment: For example, you set `inputfile` in the `menu()` function. But this is setting a **local** variable. When `readfile` is called, there's no global variable `inputfile` as it would expect. It'd need to be declared as `global inputfile` at the start of `menu`, in order to menu get a hint that it should handle the variable as a global one.

Comment: @LauroMoura ahh so when I declare a local variable under a different function I can't call upon it elsewhere? that would explain a few traceback errors.

Comment: @BenLindsay exactly. As the name implies, they are local to the scope they were created in (by the first assignment to them). Even if you had created an `inputfile` var outside `menu()`, assigning it **inside** `menu()` would actually create a different, local `inputfile`, overriding the global one.

Comment: @LauroMoura that actually helps a lot with my general understanding of Python, thanks!